# How to execute shell script from PHP with non-standard extension?

Tags: windows-7, shell, php, file-association, exec

I've Windows with shell integration installed from Git (as well as Cygwin) and the following PHP code fails to run external shell script which has `.launcher` extension:

```
<?php
  passthru("foo.sh");
  passthru("foo.launcher");
?>
```

My both `foo.sh` and `foo.launcher` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo Works!
```

When I run my PHP script, the `.sh` is executed, however `.launcher` doesn't work as it showing me the error:

> Windows can't open this file: File: foo.launcher
>
> To open this file, Windows needs to know what program you want to use it to open.

As workaround I could probably change the file association, however I think it's blocked by company policy (however I've still access to registry). So I prefer some solution which I can use from PHP perspective, if there is any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also write a wrapper script to get around this problem

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
foo.launcher
```

and then execute that script from within php.  That would avoid registry changes and company policy violations.